# Replace a default link with another link

Tags: javascript

I want change the link attribute `href` of an existing link with another link using JavaScript. How can I do this?

Here is the link:

```
<a href="defaultlink.php?go=no">See more</a><a href="defaultlink.php?go=yes">See more</a><a href="defaultlink.php?go=why">See more</a>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var len = links.replace;
for(var i=0; i<replace; i++){ 
  links[i].href = "newlink.php?+BLABLABAL";
}
```

Comment: I tested your code. It is working fine. only problem is with replace.

Comment: var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var len = links.length;
for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
{ 
    links[i].href = "newlink.php?+BLABLABA";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `links.replace` by `links.length`, since you are iterating over the links array.

Working code:

```
// This is an array of links
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 

// The length of the array
var len = links.length;

// Iterate over the array
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
  links[i].href = "https://twitter.com";
}
```

Working demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYBdgQ

Comment: Is working but remember that my link has different action like after the link you link?go=on see `<a href="defaultlink.php?go=no">See more</a><a href="defaultlink.php?go=yes">See more</a><a href="defaultlink.php?go=why">See more</a`

Comment: There is no difference, simply put the new link with the corresponding action, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your js code with this :

```
 var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var len = links.length;
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){ 
      links[i].href = "newlink.php?+BLABLABAL";
    }
```

You have to take the **length of links in var len**, and then **run the loop through len**